# Setup GoogleAnalytics on iOS

Tags: ios, google-analytics, cocoapods

I want to setup the new GoogleAnalytics on iOS. I have done it many times before, but the new pod is killing me and Googles lack of updated documentation too.

According to: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/?ver=objc

I should use pod 'Google/Analytics' to install GA via CocoaPods. BUT: Checking with cocoapods.org this does NOT reference to any GA pod.

On the other hand:
pod 'GoogleAnalytics-iOS-SDK', '~> 3.12' references to the now deprecated GA 3.12 SDK.

Instead cocoapods.org suggests:
pod 'GoogleAnalytics', '~> 3.14' which references to GA 3.14.0 SDK

Does anybody know what pod 'Google/Analytics' references to?

Next the install guide on GA Dev suggests using a configuration file. I'm used to set it up in code manually and the adding a configuration file causes my app to break referring to a SKPayment...-something. Obviousy the references are not correct setup in the pod.

So,
Which SDK should I user via cocoa pods?
Hov do I configure GA, by config file or by code?

Thanks,

Esben